# Kql Query Not Successful

Tags: azure, reporting-services, kql

I am trying to generate a report on the usage of Sensitivity Labels based on Department,Users,and certain operations mentioned in the query.

I am trying to combine 2 tables.

The first one is MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection which has information about the Sensitivity Label, the Operations, the Workload, and the UserId.While the second table is IdentityInfo, which has the User info such as AccountUPN ,Mail Address and Department name.

The issue that occurs is that on some cases 'MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection'table's UserId column has the mailadress, for example, abc@xyz.com and for some cases, it has the UPN (Employee number), 123@xyz.com.

So I am trying to join both of these tables to get all of the data together, so that I can get the desired result.

I am trying to join the 'MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection' table first with entries of AccountUPN from 'IdentityInfo' table, then trying to join 'MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection' table with 'MailAddress' from 'IdentityInfo' table, and then combining them with a union.

My Query looks like this:

```
MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection
| join kind=leftouter  IdentityInfo on ($left.UserId==$right.AccountUPN)
| union (MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection | join kind = leftouter  IdentityInfo on ($left.UserId==$right.MailAddress))
| where Operation in~ ("SensitivityLabelApplied",
    "FileSensitivityLabelApplied",
    "FileSensitivityLabelChanged",
    "SensitivityLabelUpdated",
    "SiteSensitivityLabelApplied",
    "SiteSensitivityLabelChanged")
| extend ProcessName= tostring(Common.ProcessName)
| extend Apps = strcat(Application,ProcessName)
| summarize count() by Operation, SensitivityLabelId, Department,Apps,Workload,AccountUPN,MailAddress
```

While I run this and see the required fields, I do not know if I can trust this data, primarily because of 2 reasons.

1. I have never used union and join, I do not know if this is accurately doing what I am trying to do.
2. A lot of fields(AccountUPN/MailAddress) have no entry for a lot of rows.

Question 1:
Can you please help me understand if what I am doing is correct and if it is, why am I seeing blanks.

Question 2:
Also, IdentityInfo is not a static table, it has multiple entries and keeps updating with multiple entries of the same user over a period of time.
If there is a table out there which has Information about a User's UPN,MailAddress and Department and only updates when a user is created, it will help me a lot. Please do let me know.

*EDIT : FIRST TABLE CAN ALSO HAVE SAME VALUES FOR MULTIPLE ROWS,BUT THERE IS A UNIQUE ID COLUMN THAT SEPARATES THE DATA. I NEED ALL THE DATA FROM THE FIRST TABLE.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a left outer join to join the `MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection` table with the `IdentityInfo` table twice, once on the `AccountUPN` column and once on the `MailAddress` column. You are then using a union to combine the results of the two joins. When joining the tables for the first time on matching `AccountUPN` column and `UserId` column, only all the columns from the left table(`MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection`) will have data and only matching values from the right table will have values. All other non matching rows will have null(blank values). This will happen for the second join also.  This is the reason for lot of fields have empty rows. This will also result in duplicate rows for same row in left table. To avoid this, you can take only the non-null row for each `SensitivityLabelId` after doing the union of both left outer join result. Below is the code,

```
MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection
| join kind=leftouter IdentityInfo on (($left.UserId==$right.AccountUPN))
| union (MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection | join kind = leftouter IdentityInfo on ($left.UserId==$right.MailAddress))
| sort by SensitivityLabelId asc , Department desc
| extend Rank= row_number(1, prev(SensitivityLabelId)!=SensitivityLabelId)
| where Rank == 1
//add remaining codes
```

This code will filter only one row for each `SensitivityLabelId` field. Even when multiple entries for same row is there in `IdentityInfo` table, the above code will remove the duplicates in the result set.

[demo](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)

[demo2](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)

Comment: In your demo, if I add another line in the first table:
"Label2", "FileSensitivityLabelApplied", "Workload2", "789@xyz.com",

And then hit run, the output table remains the same, whereas it shouldn't.

Comment: But you informed duplicates exists only in `identityinfo` table, Am I missing , someting?

Comment: Okay so what i meant was the first table basically captures events of all users performing certain operations. 2 different users can perform the same operation or 1 user can perform 2 different operations, and it will be captured in the first table. The MicrosoftPurviewInformationProtection table captures events/ operations performed by users on files. So labels can be repetetive. I am sorry If this wasn't clear.
So when i make my new change like i said in the first comment, 2 entries of label 2 should be visible in my final output.

Comment: Any field in 1st table will be non-repetative. Like primary key?

Comment: Other option is after unioning you can filter all rows with blank values( you can take any of the right table column name).  But this will not solve , when there are multiple entries in second table.

Comment: Yeah, there's a unique column called Id. Your second comment is something I tried but it also does not give the right answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255967/discussion-between-aswin-and-jerry).